# I am trying to stand up 2 ghost containers, with mysql on the back end with eeacms/haproxy as the load balancer in docker containers error 503

Tags: docker-compose, haproxy

I have  tried  many  configurations and scenarios  based  around this which is  mostly a  tutorial  that stops  at one  ghost  instance.  I am  trying  to scale it to 2  with  docker-deploy up -d --scale ghost=2.  When I hit  the individual  IP;s  of  the  ghost  containers , they work  but port 80  is  503.

```
version: "3.1"
volumes:
  mysql-volume:
  ghost-volume:

networks:
  ghost-network:

services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: mysql
    volumes:
      - mysql-volume:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - ghost-network
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: db
      MYSQL_USER: blog-user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: supersecret

  ghost:
    build: ./ghost
    image: laminar/ghost:3.0
    volumes:
      - ghost-volume:/var/lib/ghost/content
    networks:
      - ghost-network
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "2368"

    environment:
      database__client: mysql
      database__connection__host: mysql
      database__connection__user: blog-user
      database__connection__password: supersecret
      database__connection__database: db
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    entrypoint: ["wait-for-it.sh", "mysql", "--", "docker-entrypoint.sh"]
    command: ["node", "current/index.js"]

  haproxy:
    image: eeacms/haproxy
    depends_on:
      - ghost
    ports:
      - "80:5000"
      - "1936:1936"
    environment:
      BACKENDS: "ghost"
      DNS_ENABLED: "true"
      LOG_LEVEL: "info"
```

What I get  on   localhost:80 is  a  503  error  the  particular eeacms/haproxy image  is  supposed  to be self-configuring    any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add a backend  URL   to the environment  and  also   tell ghost it was  installed  in an alternate location  by adding  URL:  localhost:5050